# IntelliJ IDEA Java FX не видит WebView

Tags: javafx, intellij-idea, intellisense

В javaFX я новичок и столкнулся с такой проблемой.
В Scence Builder я сделал WebView, объявил его, но почему-то в контроллере ругается на WebView, то есть:

```
private **WebView** webView;
```

Ругается на то, что выделено.

Скрин:

[image: Скрин]

Answer (score 1):

Вам необходимо импортировать класс WebView. Нажмите Alt+Enter и импортируете класс javafx.scene.web.WebView.